# Jetpack Compose KeyEvent handler globally

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently developing an Android TV application using Jetpack Compose, which supports both remote control (keyboard) and gamepad inputs. Now, I wish to display different prompt texts on the interface when the user is using the remote control and the gamepad.

Initially, I thought of using `Modifier.onKeyEvent`, but I want the user to be able to respond by pressing specific keys regardless of which component has focus, so this method is not feasible.

Then, I considered handling the `onKeyDown` event within the Activity like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : androidx.activity.ComponentActivity() {
    private var mIsGamePad = false
    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        this.mIsGamePad = when (event?.source) {
            InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD,
            InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

However, this introduces a new problem, when the value of `mIsGamePad` changes, the Compose components do not redraw. The Compose components are not aware of the change in `mIsGamePad`.

So, what can I do to enable global key response through Jetpack Compose, regardless of which component currently has focus?

---

Updates:

I’ve found a solution using `LocalBroadcast`, but it might not be the most elegant. If you have a better solution, please let me know.

Here is my solution:

```kotlin
class DemoActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val INTENT_ACTION_KEY_EVENT = "Intent.action.internal.key_event"
    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        Intent(INTENT_ACTION_KEY_EVENT).putExtra("key", event)
            .let(LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)::sendBroadcast)
        // Depending on the situation, you may need to return false here.
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }

    @Composable
    fun GlobalKeyEventHandler(context: Context, onKeyEvent: (KeyEvent) -> Unit) {
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            val manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
            val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(ctx: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                    intent?.getParcelableExtra<KeyEvent>("key")
                        ?.let(onKeyEvent)
                }

            }
            manager.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(INTENT_ACTION_KEY_EVENT))
            onDispose {
                manager.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager` has been deprecated for several years. Have your `Activity` code update a viewmodel that updates a repository. Have your composables observe changes in that repository through their viewmodels.